# PHP JSON - have identical keys for JSON output from PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

Is there any way to encode a PHP array (or any other similar PHP object) into JSON while having identical keys for a JSON array?

Here is an example:

```
{"categories" : [ {"key": "data1"}, {"key": "data2"}, {"key": "data3" } ] }
```

Note that the "categories" object is an array that can be simply parsed with a for loop.
However, in PHP, it is impossible it seems to have identical keys in an associative array. So I can't have the structure above as my result from json_encode, and I have to have "key1", "key2", "key3", which prevents me from simply parsing it with a for loop in Javascript.

EDIT: Fixed JSON syntax
EDIT2: All data is different. Keys are identical.

Comment: What you show is not valid JSON. If you want to produce invalid JSON (I cannot think of a reason you might want to do so), you need to write your own encoder/decoder

Comment: @kingkero: Why is it not valid JSON?

Comment: [] should be {} because only values can be there if there were []'s

Comment: Oh, right. But isn't that just a typo?

Comment: just change your json slightly and it should work: `{"categories" : [ {"key": "data"},{ "key": "data"},{"key": "data"} ] }`

Comment: @OzanKurt No, then the last value would overwrite the previous ones. This is simply not valid.

Comment: @Jon see [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) or similar projects. Short: You can't do that. If you want to use the same key, use an array as it is intended for `{"cat":{"key":["item1","item2"]}}`

Comment: @kingkero: Of course you *can* do that, because RFC 7159 says that keys "*should* be unique" and not "*must* be unique". I can't think of a reason to do it, and I don't know how implementation X would handle this JSON, but that doesn't mean it's invalid.

Comment: Fixed. I double checked the syntax this time, it's correct.

Comment: And guys, I know for a fact that I can do that since I already did that before and that's why I am asking. All I want to know if its possible in PHP. I know already it's possible in javascript.

Comment: So you completely changed your orignal string based on a comment. And what is the problem now?

Comment: I want to output this in PHP from a PHP array or another PHP object that has associative mapping like that.

Comment: Do you still have the question? Your categories object should contain three different objects with the same keys now and you could easily loop over them.

Comment: All data is different, sorry, wasn't clear from the syntax. When I call categories[0].key I get "data1"

Comment: @jeroen this doesn't means that the json isn't valid

Comment: @OzanKurt I did not mean your version, I meant the OP's original version. With the curly braces it's perfectly valid although a bit useless :-)

Comment: @jeroen Aha, okay then... Because were trying to teach someone the right way.

Comment: The reason why I decided to use this syntax is because I would never know how many "keys" I would have, and my code does not depend strictly on how many "keys" there are in the array. I just wanted to parse it quickly with a for loop and store them locally.

Comment: You'd better go for @kingkero's syntax as it seems kind of pointless to repeat the same key for every value you have.

Comment: Yup, I realized that when I wrote the code. Again thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = [
    'categories' => [
        ['key' => 'data'],
        ['key' => 'data'],
        ['key' => 'data']
    ]
];

echo json_encode($array);
```

That's the same array structure as in your JSON. JSON has the same rules regarding unique keys as PHP does.

<sub>(Using PHP 5.4+ array syntax here.)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Use the php json_encode() function to turn a PHP array into a JSON string.

Reversed: json_decode()

Example:

```
<?php

$json = '{"categories" : { "key1": {"first":"1. value"}, "key2": "data", "key3": "data" } }';

$array = json_decode($json,true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Will output:

```
Array
(
    [categories] => Array
        (
            [key1] => Array
                (
                    [first] => 1. value
                )

            [key2] => data
            [key3] => data
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be straightforward:

```
echo json_encode([
  'categories' => [
    ['key' => 'data'],
    ['key' => 'data'],
    ['key' => 'data'],
  ],
]);
```

Also, you can simply reverse engineer the structure by doing:

```
$str = '{"categories" : [ {"key": "data1"}, {"key": "data2"}, {"key": "data3" } ] }';
$arr = json_decode($str);

var_export($arr);
```